# MemoryCache get in Disposed state Magically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, base-class-library, memorycache

I did many tests, my MemoryCache instances get disposed after some time and always returns null when I call Get method. I think that is after PollingInterval.

To simulate you can start a new webapp and write this code:

```
    private static MemoryCache mem = new MemoryCache("MyCache");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string key = "MyKey";
        mem.Set(key, "MyValue", new CacheItemPolicy() {AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1), Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable});
        LtrValue.Text = mem.Get(key) as string;
    }
```

I configured the PollingInterval to 30 hours an seems to work.

I thought could be the AppDomain Unload, but after some investigation I don´t think that is it:

1-) MSDN says to use MemoryCache for ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235(v=vs.100).aspx
And says that ASP.NET 4 cache is built with ObjectCache:

In ASP.NET 4, caching is implemented by using the ObjectCache class.

2-) AppDomain unload would reset statics variable, creating new MemoryCache instances.

3-) I attached a event to AppDomain Unload like the MemoryCache does(I saw the decompiled source) in my test it wasn´t called and memorycache get  disposed.

References:

The same post at MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/1233ffb3-6480-431b-94ca-1190f96cf5f6

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/0a666d5e-9bda-47bd-8dd3-98d32eb5fe60

[MemoryCache Empty : Returns null after being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-disposed-in-web-application)

[System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache strange behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767604/system-runtime-caching-memorycache-strange-behavior)

[MemoryCache empty just after adding an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849000/memorycache-empty-just-after-adding-an-object)

[MemoryCache does not obey memory limits in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895956/memorycache-strangeness)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MemoryCache Disposed in Web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-disposed-in-web-application)

Comment: Scott Hanselman reports a bug in .Net4 that may be affecting you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-disposed-in-web-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really a bug, it was fixed in .NET 4.5 and they are working to back-port to .NET 4

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1233ffb3-6480-431b-94ca-1190f96cf5f6/